# A very basic java outprint issue

Tags: java, arrays

I want a specific command to print on the same line but it prints on different lines and I can't figure out a simple fix for it.

```
package lab10;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int numItems;
        int[] items;


        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of items");

        numItems = scan.nextInt(); 

        items = new int [numItems];

        if (items.length > 0);{
            System.out.println("Enter the value of all items"
                    + "(seperated by space):");
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {


                int val = scan.nextInt();
                items[i]= val;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
            if (i== 0) {
                System.out.println("The values are:" + items[i]);

            }else {
                System.out.println("The values are:" + items[i] + "," + " ");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected result:**

Enter the number of items

3

Enter the value of all items(separated by space):

1 2 3

The values are:1, 2, 3

**Actual result:**

Enter the number of items

3

Enter the value of all items(separated by space):

1 2 3

The values are:1

The values are:2,

The values are:3,

Comment: well that is what `println` does.  Try just using `print`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `i == 0` you want `items.length == 0`, and "is" not "are". Also, you'll need additional logic to handle joining the values (and use `System.out.print` to avoid printing a newline). Like,

```
if (items.length != 0) {
    System.out.print("The values are: ");
}
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    if (items.length == 1) {
        System.out.print("The value is: " + items[i]);
    } else {
        if (i != 0) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.print(items[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach may be cleaner.

```
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ", "The values are:", "");
        if (items.length > 0){

            System.out.println("Enter the value of all items"
                + "(seperated by space):");
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {


                int val = scan.nextInt();
                items[i]= val;
                joiner.add(items[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```

BTW, at this line

```
if (items.length > 0);{
```

the semicolon(`;`) should not be there.

Comment: Also *The values are* is incorrect English for a singular item

Comment: @ScaryWombat you are right, I just want to simplify the logic. :D

Comment: `joiner.add(items[i]);` does not compile.  Also with `System.out.println(joiner.toString());` , `joiner` is out of scope.